# Arduino millis() in Python

Tags: python-2.7, arduino-ide

Is there a function like millis() from Arduino IDE in Python? I tried to manipulate date and time stuff in python but can't find or get anything close to the millis() function from Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

[micropython millis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3temx.png)

Try to type:
import utime
utime.
then press Tab.
Useful link:
https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/utime.html

Answer (score 0):

```
start = pyb.millis()
while pyb.elapsed_millis(start) < 1000:
    # Perform some operation
```